# Login with Verisign OpenID

Tags: support, openid

I've been trying to login with my VeriSign OpenID on my mobile phone. The first two attempts were seen as suspicious, whereas the third said unknown OpenID provider. Does this not work on the mobile website, or am I just missing something?

Comment: Does your problem  occur on other SE sites, or is it unique to B&CG?

Comment: Tried on SO, same issue.

Comment: Although marked as duplicate, as stated, this was a mobile issue. It appears to be working normally at the moment.

Comment: It works for boardgames, but not SO. Still suspicious request on the latter. I was too early with my comment.